# Why does :io.columns fail when running through the escript

Tags: io, command-line-interface, elixir

I'm working on a CLI interface, and wanted to get the number of columns of the current terminal being used.

I found [the documentation for :io.columns](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#columns-0), and it works like a charm within iex, but once I compile the escript binary with mix, by running `mix escript.build`, and I run it, then `:io.columns` returns `{error, enotsup}`.

What is happening that the IO Device isn't bubbling up properly? How can I access the columns number?

Comment: This might be [a bug affecting recent versions of Erlang](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2017-September/093270.html).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found out *why* it isn't working, but I'll post the solution I used: **talk directly to bash**

`$ tput cols` gives the number of columns, in bash, so

For elixir: `System.cmd("tput", ["cols"])`
For erlang: `:os.cmd('tput cols')`

Comment: Mac system:

Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V9.0.4  (abort with ^G)
(test1@127.0.0.1)1> os:cmd("tput cols").
"80\n"
(test1@127.0.0.1)2> io:columns().
{ok,141}


but is bash

$ tput cols
141
`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-717) in recent Erlang/OTP releases. The bug will most likely be fixed in the next release.

The following workaround may be useful until the bug has been fixed:

```erlang
-module(test).

-export([main/1]).

main(_) ->
    io:format("Nr of columns: ~p~n",[my_columns()]).

my_columns() ->
    Parent = self(),
    spawn(
      fun()->
              Port = erlang:open_port({spawn, "tput cols"},
                                      [use_stdio, in, stream,{line, 10000}]),
              Columns =
                  receive
                      {Port, {data, {_,Line}}} ->
                          erlang:list_to_integer(Line)
                  end,
              Parent ! {my_columns_msg, Columns},
              spawn(fun Reader() ->
                            receive
                                {_Port, {data, {_,_}}} ->
                                    Reader();
                                _ -> ok
                            end
                    end)
      end),
    receive
        {my_columns_msg, Columns} -> Columns
    end.
```

Note that calling `os:cmd("tput cols")` (suggested in @nichochar's answer) does not work because `stdout` and `stdin` will not be connected to the terminal when `tput` is invoked by `os:cmd/1`.